# Android crashes when executing after installing oneSingal React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

In react native, after adding onesignal package I am getting this error. Can anybody help me about this issue??

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
25 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 20 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1.
> AAR metadata file: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3db9d940a0e1f63c8669f0ed70305a71/transformed/work-runtime-2.7.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1.
> AAR metadata file: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3db9d940a0e1f63c8669f0ed70305a71/transformed/work-runtime-2.7.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

And my build options like this:

> ext {
> buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
> minSdkVersion = 21
> compileSdkVersion = 30
> targetSdkVersion = 30
> ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
> }

Comment: change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31

Comment: I changed them but it does not work

Comment: did you properly follow the one signal installation steps? Please go through https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup

Comment: Are you using managed or bare workflow?